# How to efficiently count the number of two word combinations in human names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, nlp, time-complexity

I have a dataframe with a single column which contains the names of people as shown below.

```
name
--------------
john doe
john david doe
doe henry john
john henry
```

I want to count the number of time each two words appear together in a name regardless of the order. In this example, the words `john` and `doe` appear in the same same three times names `john doe`, `john henry doe` and `doe john`.

**Expected output**

```
name1 | name2 | count
----------------------
david | doe   | 1
doe   | henry | 1
doe   | john  | 3
henry | john  | 2
```

Notice that `name1` is the word that comes first in alphabetical order. Currently I have a  brute force solution.

1. Create a list of all unique words in the dataframe
2. For each unique word `W` in this list, filter the records in the original data frame which contain this `W`
3. From the filtered records, count frequency of other words. This gives the number of time `W` appears with various other words

**Question**: This works fine for small number of records but is not efficient if we have a large number of records as it runs in quadratic complexity. How can it generate the output in a faster way? Is there any function or package that can give these counts?

**Note**: I tried using n-gram extraction from NLP packages but this over estimates the counts because it internally appends all the names to form a long string due to which the last word on a name and the first word of the next name shows up as a a sequence of words in the appended string which adds up to the count.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which is still quadratic but over smaller `n` and also hides most of it in compiled code (which should hopefully execute faster):

```py
from itertools import combinations

combs = df['name'].apply(lambda x:list(combinations(sorted(x.split()),2)))
counts = Counter(combs.explode())
res = pd.Series(counts).rename_axis(['name1', 'name2']).reset_index(name='count')
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   name1  name2  count
0    doe   john      3
1  david    doe      1
2  david   john      1
3    doe  henry      1
4  henry   john      2
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the below:

```
import itertools

# 1) Create combinations of 2 from all the names using itertools().
l = [a for b in df.name.tolist() for a in b]
c = {c for c in itertools.combinations(l, 2) if c[0] != c[1]}
df_counts = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["name1", "name2"])

# 2) Create a new column iterating through rows to check of each name is contained in each list of words & sum the boolean outputs.
df_counts["counts"] = df_counts.apply(lambda row: sum([row["name1"] in l and row["name2"] in l for l in df.name.to_list()]), axis=1)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Did you actually test this code? `l` does not contain what you think it does...

Comment: Yes - tested, what do you get?

Comment: I get this for `l`: `['j', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'd', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'e', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'n', 'r', 'y', ' ', 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'n', 'r', 'y']`

Comment: I see, depends on how you set up the name column, in my case I created lists, so my code just gets all elements within each list creating a big list with all names. In your case, you probably used strings so to get the same you would have to do `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([name.split() for name in df.names]))`.  This will create a list of lists and then combine all those lists into one.

Comment: In the question the data appears to be strings, not lists

Comment: It is not specified, we do not have a dataframe in the question. The important is to understand why you got that output and what is the best solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is an instance of 'Association Rule Mining' with just 2 items per transaction. It has simple algorithms like 'Aperiori' as well as efficient ones like 'FP-Growth' and you can find a lot of [resources](https://towardsdatascience.com/apriori-association-rule-mining-explanation-and-python-implementation-290b42afdfc6?gi=df7c4db5c803) to learn that.